# How to find the work done by gravity without using calculus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

The problem is as follows:

We have a rocket with a mass of $m$, which left the earth and came to a height $h$ with the terminal velocity $v$. I need to calculate the work done by the force of gravity over the entire flight.

I must not use calculus. I don't really know how to go about this.The best idea is to state that the change in energy is equal to the work done to the rocket, i.e. $\Delta E=W$. I have enough information to compute $\Delta E$, but I think that $W$ is the total work done on the rocket, both from the force of gravity and the force that pulls the rocket upwards.

Comment: Look *carefully* at the wording of the problem and your uncertainty will disappear.

Comment: @garyp Are you referring to the word 'entire'? I have considered writing $\Delta U=W$, i.e. to take into the account only the gravitational potential energy. But the question remains, why am I given a terminal velocity?

Comment: No, not that word.   A phrase.  Keep looking.

Comment: Think: Does the work done by gravity depend on the velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since gravity is a conservative force, the net work done by gravity will be final P.E. - initial P.E. (by P.E. I mean gravitational potential energy). By saying that the rocket reaches a terminal velocity, I believe the question means that the rocket is 'out of' the gravitational field of the earth or the final P.E. $\approx$ $0$. Thus, your answer should be $mgr_e$ where $r_e$ is radius of the  earth.